# How to measure redirection latency using Python requests library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, python-requests

Redirect latency: This time is between 301 and 200 or maybe the time between two redirects is 301.

Like a Chrome extension:

[image]

How to measure redirection latency using the requests library?

```
import requests
r = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/3'
r = requests.head(r, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
r.elapsed
```

`r.elapsed` is not what I need, it shows the time between sending the request and the first content it receives.

Comment: A redirect is two GETs. The first one plus the second one plus a small amount of time to control the flow to the second one. Measure both with and without redirect enabled. The cost of the redirect is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Using the `requests` library, you would have to set the `allow_redirects` parameter to `False` and have a loop where you look up for the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) response header (which indicates the URL to redirect a page to), then perform a new request to that URL, and finally, measure the total elapsed time.

However, you may find it easier to do that with [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org) library, which is very similar to Python `requests`, but with more features. You can [set the `follow_redirects` parameter to `False`](https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) (which is the default value anyway) and use the `.next_request` attribue of the [`Response`](https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#response) object to get the redirection URL into an already constructed [`Request`](https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#request) object. As described earlier, you can then have a loop to send each request and measure their response time (= transport latency + processing time), separately. The `response.elapsed` returns a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object with the time elapsed from sending the request to the arrival of the response. By adding all the response times together, you can measure the total time elapsed. Example:

```py
import httpx

url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/3'

with httpx.Client() as client:
    r = client.get(url, follow_redirects=False)
    print(r.url, r.elapsed, '', sep='\n')
    total = r.elapsed.total_seconds()
    
    while 300 < r.status_code < 400:
        r = client.send(r.next_request)
        print(r.url, r.elapsed, '', sep='\n')
        total += r.elapsed.total_seconds()
        
    print(f'Total time elapsed: {total} s')
```

### Option 2

Set the `follow_redirects` parameter to `True` and use the `.history` attribute of the [`Response`](https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#response) object to get a list of responses that led to the final URL. The `.history` property contains a list of any redirect responses that were followed, in the order in which they were made. You can measure the elapsed time for each request, as well as the total elapsed time, as demonstrated in Option 1 above. Example:

```py
import httpx

url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/3'

with httpx.Client() as client:
    r = client.get(url, follow_redirects=True)
    
    total = 0
    if r.history:
        for resp in r.history:
            print(resp.url, resp.elapsed, '', sep='\n')
            total += resp.elapsed.total_seconds()

    print(r.url, r.elapsed, '', sep='\n')
    total += r.elapsed.total_seconds()
    print(f'Total time elapsed: {total} s')
```

In Python `requests` (instead of `httpx`), the above approach would be as follows:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/3'

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
     
    total = 0
    if r.history:
        for resp in r.history:
            print(resp.url, resp.elapsed, '', sep='\n')
            total += resp.elapsed.total_seconds()

    print(r.url, r.elapsed, '', sep='\n')
    total += r.elapsed.total_seconds()
    print(f'Total time elapsed: {total} s')
```

### Note

If you would like to **ignore the body from the response** (as you might not need it, and hence, you wouldn't want to have it loaded into your RAM, especially when using Option 2, where every response is saved to `history`), you can use `HEAD` instead of `GET` request. Examples are given below.

Using `httpx`:

```py
r = client.head(url, ...
```

Using `requests`:

```py
r = session.head(url, ...
```

Comment: that was perfect. Which method do you think is good? Indeed, you did not use the time library!!

Comment: Which method is more reliable? Because the output is very different in each of the methods.

Comment: Either method would work just fine.